# Transposing multiple columns is a row

Tags: text-processing, columns

I need to transpose a file from this format

```
1 2 3 4  
6 7 8 9   
a b c d   
f g h i j
```

to this format

```
1 2 6 7 a b f g  
3 4 8 9 c d h k
```

two columns in a single row in the way posted above.

Any suggestions??

Comment: where is the `k` in your output coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `k` in your output is a typo, here is one way to do it in bash

```
paste -d $'\n' <(cut -f1,2 -d' ' input.txt | tr -s $'\n' ' ') \
<(cut -f3,4 -d' ' input.txt | tr -s $'\n' ' ')
```

which produces

```
1 2 6 7 a b f g 
3 4 8 9 c d h i
```

GNU awk-based solution

```
awk '{for (j = 1; j <= NF; ++j) arr[NR,j] = $j};
END{
  for (j=1; j <=NF; j+=2) for(i=1; i <=NR; ++i){
    printf i == 1?"": " "; printf arr[i,j]" "arr[i,j+1];
    if (i == NR) printf "\n"
  }
}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Any ideas how to apply it on a 1000 column file?

Comment: @user43405 - you should either ask that as a 2nd question (independent of this) or edit this question with some "more" of that sample data.

Comment: @user43405, I agree with slm, you should post a different question. FWIW, i have added a memory-intensive awk solution that should work for more than 4 columns. If you post a different question, you are likely to get better solutions than this from the experts on this forum